# at which time it may be renewed

Tags: grammar

Q: What does this sentence exactly mean?

> The permit is valid for one year from date of issue, at which time it may be renewed.

(1) If I got the permit at the beginning of the year 2022, I could renew it within 2022.

Or

(2) If I got the permit at the beginning of the year 2022, I could renew it at the end of the year 2022.

Source: Inside Reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a badly written sentence.

"At which time" refers back to a *time point* previous mentioned. The only time point mentioned is the date of issue. I don't believe you are meant to renew immediately after issue.

I believe it should have said:

- The permit is valid **until** one year from date of issue, at which time it may be renewed.

Using the word 'until' changes what follows to a calculation from the date of issue, ultimately meaning the date one year later. And it is at *that* time it can be renewed.

**OR**

- The permit is valid for one year from the date of issue, **after which time** it may be renewed.

"After which time" refers to a *time period* previously mentioned, in other words, the 'one year'. So, when the year has passed, you can renew.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, in a phrase like "at which time", "which" is an adjective that refers back to the time (in this case) previously mentioned. It can be used with other nouns. Like, "You will be assigned an advisor, which person will help you schedule your classes." "Which" here refers back to the assigned advisor. (Sort of like a pronoun, I guess.)

So this sentence is saying that you can renew the permit when it expires in one year. If you took this sentence absolutely literally, that would mean that you must renew it on the exact day that it expires. In real life, I doubt that's the case. Usually you can renew things like a license or permit for some period before the expiration date, like a month or so. If you got the permit on January 1, 2023, you can probably renew it starting December 1, give or take. But you'd have to check.

It reminds me, many years ago when I worked for a Political Action Committee, there was a bill in the state legislature that said that a certain document related to keeping your personal data private had to be renewed once a year. You were not allowed to renew before the year was up, and if you waited until after the year was up, the information would be released. So at least as the law was worded, you had to renew on the exact day that it expired. I recall we were trying to get that changed but I forget what happened.